# With the Telerik Silverlight controls, how can I cast a RadMaskedTextBox as a TextBox

Tags: silverlight, telerik, radmaskedtextbox

I am trying to determine if a Telerik RadMaskedTextBox allows multiline input.

I the debugger, I was able to find and check the .AcceptsReturn property of the underlying textbox, using:

```
((System.Windows.Controls.TextBox)(((Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadMaskedTextBox)(this)).textBox)).AcceptsReturn;
```

However, when I paste that into my C# code, the compiler complains that RadMaskedTextBox cannot be cast as a TextBox

A little weird, since the Debugger allows it.

The debugger also allows:

```
((System.Windows.Controls.TextBox)(((Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadMaskedTextBox)(this)).textBox)).TextWrapping
```

this the compiler complains about

Any ideas?

Comment: Is `textBox` `protected` or `private`, perhaps?

Comment: @Todda; Yes, TextBox of this control is a private member of the RadMaskedTextBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Telerik Support Forum:

The underlying TextBox is of type ExtendedTextBox. You can access it like so:

```
var innerBox = this.masktextBox.ChildrenOfType<Telerik.Windows.Controls.MaskedTextBox.ExtendedTextBox>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do this in the past (sorry can't remember the exact way to go about this) but I had to traverse the object and find the textbox control.  If I can find the project where I did it I will update my answer.

Comment: So I looked into it and the TextBox of this control is actually a private member of the RadMaskedTextBox.  I think before I ended up creating my own class that gave me access to the textbox using Reflector.  You may be able to use reflection to get access to the member but I personally wouldn't go down that route.