# With the Telerik Silverlight controls, how can I determine if RadMaskedTextBox allows multiline input

Tags: silverlight, telerik, radmaskedtextbox, telerik-radmaskedtextbox

Using the Telerik RadMaskedTextBox control in C#, how can I tell if the underlying textbox allows multiline input

**Edit:** The Silverlight version does not appear to contain the .Textmode property and returns

'Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadMaskedTextBox' does not contain a definition for 'TextMode' ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Telerik Support Forum:

The underlying TextBox is of type ExtendedTextBox. You can access it like so:

```
var innerBox = this.masktextBox.ChildrenOfType<Telerik.Windows.Controls.MaskedTextBox.ExtendedTextBox>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always try [reading the documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/input/maskedtextbox.html).

> To allow the RadMaskedTextBox to display its content in multiple lines you have to set the TextMode property to MultiLine

Work backwards to get whether the textbox is single- or multi-line.

See [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/input/radinput-telerik.webcontrols.radmaskedtextbox-textmode.html) for the documentation on the `TextMode` property.

Comment: I deserved that for not being clear; .TextMode is not in the Silverlight version; Question edited to add information.  See related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085317/in-c-how-can-i-cast-a-radmaskedtextbox-as-a-textbox